# SpriteKit Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a `ViewController` that creates and presents an `SKScene *scene` as I will show below. Currently, I am presenting a scene subclass that contains an extensive amount of nodes, objects, etc.

I recently began to make sure that I was not experiencing and performance issues, when I noticed that I appear to have a memory leak, about + 1 to 2 mbs . Alarmed, I began removing items until all that I had left was the following method in my VC... :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
        skView.showsPhysics = YES;

        // Create and configure the scene.

        SKScene *testScene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)];

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:testScene];
    }
    // Do things after here pertaining to initial loading of view.
}
```

To my surprise, the application memory loaded at roughly 1.2 MB, and **still** continued to grow each second (this time by ~0.3 mbs). I am lost, and can not understand why even presenting absolutely nothing could cause such an issue. If anyone knows what I am missing please let me know - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Realized the answer was extremely simple.. I'm glad I noticed to check this so I figured I would post the fix just in case anyone experiences the same issue.

All I had to do....remove this line.

```
skView.showsPhysics = YES;
```

Guess sprite kit holds on to each physics boundary that it "draws", and given that each nodes position does move slightly due to the smallest of numerical inaccuracies, it basically redraws every shape every FPS. So, happy coding!

Comment: it would be nice wouldn't it!? Perhaps I'm waiting for SO to allow me to accept it given I asked it 15 hrs ago..but thank you for your concern